# Can IntText ipywidget buttons be re-styled?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

The "step buttons" on the side of an `ipywidgets.IntText` widget are too small to my taste, and I would like to restyle them (make them bigger, maybe put the "previous" one on the left of the text field, ...).

Could anyone point me to any way of fiddling with those?

[image]

My knee-jerk reaction was to define new buttons to the same effect, but then I thought 'well someone must have done that nicely'.

My quest lead me from reading docs to the deep weeds of the ipywidgets package code... to realise I couldn't even find where those buttons are defined. Help please? :-)